# How do we get an optional class attribute in Python?

Tags: python

For dictionary we can use `.get` method. What about a class's attribute and provide a default value?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`hasattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) and [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

For example:

```
hasattr(foo, 'bar')
```

would return `True` if `foo` has an attribute named `bar`, otherwise `False` and

```
getattr(foo, 'bar', 'quux')
```

would return `foo.bar` if it exists, otherwise defaults to `quux`.

Comment: +1. You might want to mention EAFP and `try:` / `except AttributeError:`

Answer (score 4):

It's dead simple: use a keyword argument.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, my_foo=None):
...         self.my_foo = my_foo
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.my_foo
>>> repr(f.my_foo)
'None'
>>> f2 = Foo(2)
>>> f2.my_foo
2
```

If you are looking for an object which does not have an attribute until you set it, Jason's idea is pretty good unless you directly refer to the attribute. You'll have to work around the `AttributeError` you'll get. Personally, I'm not a fan of creating objects which must be constantly surrounded by `try`/`except` blocks just for the sake of not setting an instance attribute.

Python isn't much for getters and setters. However, you can use [`property()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) to work around this problem:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         pass
...     def get_my_foo(self):
...         return getattr(self, "_my_foo", "there's no my_foo")
...     def set_my_foo(self, foo):
...         self._my_foo = foo
...     my_foo = property(get_my_foo, set_my_foo)
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.my_foo
"there's no my_foo"
>>> f.my_foo = "foo!"
>>> f.my_foo
'foo!'
```

It works just as well to call `get_my_foo` and `set_my_foo`, if you like. An added benefit is that you can omit the setter to make a read-only attribute, provided someone using your object doesn't change the underlying `_my_foo`.