# General syntax python question : from typed language to untyped one

Tags: python, typescript, model, definition

I'am new to python language.
And my question is certainly a naive one and concerning python syntax.

I am at the step where I must go from theory to practice.

here is a class (a typescript one) I want to translate to python language.

```
class Category {
    id: number;
    type: 'shop'|'blog';
    name: string;
    slug: string;
    path: string;
    image: string|null;
    items: number;
    customFields: CustomFields;
    parents?: Category[]|null;
    children?: Category[]|null;
}
```

as python is untyped language I've got doubts about how to translate :

- the optional property : '?'
- the associated class :  customFields: CustomFields;
- the arrays of associated class (that are self associated) and that are nullable :  children?: Category[]|null;

I've always worked with typed language until now and it's destabilising my habits to just write nothing.

would that look like this (it's a model for django.db migration):

```
>from django.db import models

    >>class Category(models.Model):
    >>>    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    >>>   type: 'shop'|'blog'
    >>>    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    >>>    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    >>>    path = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

and then ... ?

could you provide also some tuto, doc, example where you learn python in pratice ?
thanks to all of you !

Comment: TypeScript is a proper superset of ECMAScript. You can literally just delete all types and then you have the exact same thing in ECMAScript, a dynamically typed language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's best to learn the language by following the documentation for it, there are enough examples in the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/

If you want to learn Django, there are quite a lot of tutorials. But first of all, look here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/

As for your example with the Category Class
The id is determined automatically and it is not necessary to explicitly specify it in the model, see more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/

Comment: thanks !!!! (especially for the last link) . It looks much more what I was expecting. (something like field definition like codeFirst/entityframework.

Comment: No problem, good luck! @Rémi Duplan

Answer (score 1):

When you define a function in Python you can enforce static typing but its not necessary. In case you need to have a static typing enforced you can do something like this.

```
//for functions
def addition(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b
addition(4,10)

//For Variables or attributes
name: str = 'test'
age: int = 10
rating: float = 1.11
is_exist: bool = True
```

There are more things found in python documentation related to typing in case
you can refer [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you must enforce typing in your Python code, take a [look at isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance). 
For optional Class attributes in Python, you can use keyword arguments as [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18087519/15921941).